# Pandas Dataframe column with numpy arrays to Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame that includes a column with in each row a Numpy array of fixed length (say 30) with integers. However, I cannot find a way to split the np array and for each integer in the array, create a new DataFrame column 0 ... 29.

For example (C consists of `np.ndarray`s):

```
   A  B  C
1  0  0  [0,3,4,...]
2  1  1  [0,1,2,...]
3  2  2  [3,4,5,...]
4  3  3  [5,6,7,...]
```

Should be:

```
   A  B  0  1  2  ... 29
1  0  0  0  3  4  ...
2  1  1  0  1  2  ...
3  2  2  3  4  5  ...
4  3  3  5  6  7  ...
```

I can do it for one array `s` by doing `pd.DataFrame(s).T`, but not for every row at once (by using something like `apply()`).

Is there a general solution, if a column would consist of lists instead of np array?

Comment: `df.C.apply(pd.Series)` then you need `pd.concat` it back

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns, check the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Err, okay. This appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Wen Perfect, I had the feeling it would be as simple as that.